# How to redirect to another page eg main.py after user fill in and click register button and store it on .ini local database on python using kivy

Tags: python, redirect, pycharm, kivy, storage

So am not that good with python because am coming from php, and I want to develop this app, and want to use local storage to store user registration data after they register they will be redirected to the main.py page, so here is the registration_screen.py page code for registration and its code with useful #comment for easy understanding, please help me please.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.config import ConfigParser
import subprocess


# Define the registration screen
class RegistrationScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # Create a vertical box layout for the registration screen
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=40, spacing=20)

        # Create text fields for username, email, and phone number
        self.username_field = MDTextField(hint_text="Username")
        self.email_field = MDTextField(hint_text="Email")
        self.phone_field = MDTextField(hint_text="Phone Number")

        # Create a button for registration
        register_button = MDFlatButton(text="Register", on_release=self.register)

        # Add widgets to the layout
        layout.add_widget(self.username_field)
        layout.add_widget(self.email_field)
        layout.add_widget(self.phone_field)
        layout.add_widget(register_button)

        # Add the layout to the screen
        self.add_widget(layout)

    # Method to handle registration process
    def register(self, *args):
        # Retrieve user input from text fields
        username = self.username_field.text
        email = self.email_field.text
        phone = self.phone_field.text

        # Store user registration data locally
        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read('registration.ini')

        if 'Registration' not in config.sections():
            config.add_section('Registration')

        # Set user data
        config.set('Registration', 'username', username)
        config.set('Registration', 'email', email)
        config.set('Registration', 'phone', phone)

        # Write data to file
        with open('registration.ini', 'w') as config_file:
            config.write(config_file)

        # Open main.py using subprocess.Popen when registration is successful
        subprocess.Popen(["python", "main.py"])


# Load the KV string defining the screen
kv = '''
    <RegistrationScreen>:
        name: "registration_screen"
    '''

# Load the KV string into the application
Builder.load_string(kv)


# Define the MDApp subclass
class RegistrationApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Create a screen manager to manage different screens
        self.manager = ScreenManager()

        # Add the RegistrationScreen as the first screen
        self.manager.add_widget(RegistrationScreen())

        # Return the screen manager
        return self.manager


# Run the RegistrationApp
if __name__ == "__main__":
    RegistrationApp().run()
```

now here is the registration.ini file which contains

[Registration]
username =
email =
phone =

and here is the main.py page code they are suppose to redirect to after registration, but instead when they click the register button from registration_screen.py they are not redirected to main.py and the code in registration.ini file gets deleted, please help me make this app a possibility because i am really getting frustrated and down, heres the main.py code where they are suppose to be redirected to.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigation
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
<MDBottomNavigation>:
   MDBottomNavigationItem:
      name: 'screen1'
      text: 'Android'
      icon: 'android'
      MDLabel:
         text: 'Android'
         halign: 'center'

   MDBottomNavigationItem:
      name: 'screen2'
      text: 'Apple'
      icon: 'apple'
      MDLabel:
         text: 'Apple'
         halign: 'center'

   MDBottomNavigationItem:
      name: 'screen3'
      text: 'Linux'
      icon: 'linux'
      MDLabel:
         text: 'Linux'
         halign: 'center'

   MDBottomNavigationItem:
      name: 'screen4'
      text: 'Windows'
      icon: 'microsoft-windows'
      MDLabel:
         text: 'Windows'
         halign: 'center'

   MDBottomNavigationItem:
      name: 'screen5'
      text: 'YourItem'
      icon: 'linux'
      MDLabel:
         text: 'YourItem'
         halign: 'center'
'''

class Screen1(Screen):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass

class Screen3(Screen):
    pass

class Screen4(Screen):
    pass

class Screen5(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
sm.add_widget(Screen3(name='screen3'))
sm.add_widget(Screen4(name='screen4'))
sm.add_widget(Screen5(name='screen5'))

class TutorialsPointApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        return MDBottomNavigation()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TutorialsPointApp().run()
```

When clicked it delete the entire code in registration.ini and dosent redirect to main.py page after clicking the register button, please help me make this project a possibility.

Comment: Wow so nobody know how to rectify this code on stackoverflow,  please someone please a Hero.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are getting an uncaught `Exception` from your code:

```
config.write(config_file)
```

The `write()` method takes no arguments as it writes to the last read file.
Try changing that line to:

```
config.write()
```

In fact, you don't need the code:

```
with open('registration.ini', 'w') as config_file:
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your audience, but I really don't need the code solved anymore, python kivy was giving me too many debug issues so I left it and switched to cordova which uses javascript so it easier now.